# Javascript how the better way to code nested callback?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have 3 layer callbacks like this :

```js
    app.post('/', (req, res) => {
        var filename = `outputs/${Date.now()}_output.json`;
        let trainInput = req.files.trainInput;
        let trainOutput = req.files.trainInput;
        let testInput = req.files.trainInput;

        //first
        trainInput.mv(`inputs/${req.body.caseName}/train_input.csv`, function (err) {
            if (err) return res.status(500).send(err);
            //second
            trainOutput.mv(`inputs/${req.body.caseName}/train_output.csv`, function (err) {
                if (err) return res.status(500).send(err);
                //third
                testInput.mv(`inputs/${req.body.caseName}/test_input.csv`, function (err) {
                    if (err) return res.status(500).send(err);

                    res.send('success');
                });
            });
        });   
    });
```

In this case, there are only 3 file uploads. In another case, I have more than 10 file uploads, and it makes 10 layer callbacks. I know it because of JavaScript asynchronous.

Is there any way, with this case, to make a beautiful code? This is because when it 10 layer callbacks, the code looks horizontally weird.

Thanks

Comment: I would use `Promise`s and `async`/`await` to straighten this up.

Comment: Check out promises. You might want to have a look here for a start: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/promises

They are made for cases like the one you're describing.

Comment: I use npm package, it only have callback

Comment: Do you need them in a row? I mean is it a workflow that they are one after each other and only if error?

Comment: I need to do that with sequence, so 1. save train_input, 2. save train_output, 3. save test_input, 4. after that there is some proccess, to extract data from all files and manipulate it

Comment: *I use npm package* - what package? *it only have callback* - why is this a problem? Promisify it or use a package that supports a promise (this depends on the package, which you didn't list).

Comment: finally I use bluebird http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/getting-started.html , it really help. thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 6):

You can use the following code to make you code look better and avoid callback hell

```
app.post('/', async (req, res) => {
    var filename = `outputs/${Date.now()}_output.json`;
    let trainInput = req.files.trainInput;
    let trainOutput = req.files.trainInput;
    let testInput = req.files.trainInput;
    try {
        var result1 = await trainInput.mv(`inputs/${req.body.caseName}/train_input.csv`);
        var result2 = await trainInput.mv(`inputs/${req.body.caseName}/train_output.csv`);
        var result2 = await testInput.mv(`inputs/${req.body.caseName}/test_input.csv`);
        res.send('success');
    }
    catch (error) {
        res.status(500).send(error);
    }
});
```

Comment: note that async await is only supported in ["late node-7 and above"](https://node.green/#ES2017-features-async-functions)

Answer (score 3):

You can make the functions return a Promise

I advice to make one function because you do the same thing 3 times. In this case I called the function 'save' but you can call it what ever you want. The first parameter is the file end the second the output filename.

```js
function save(file, output) = return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  file.mv(`inputs/${req.body.caseName}/${output}`, err => 
  if (err) return reject(err)
  resolve()
})

Promise.all([
    save(req.files.trainInput, 'train_input.csv'),
    save(req.files.trainInput, 'train_output.csv'),
    save(req.files.trainInput, 'test_input.csv')
])
.then(_ => res.send(200))
.catch(err => res.send(400);
```

Answer (score 0):

What version of Node you using? If async/await is available that cleans it up a bunch.

```
const moveCsv = (file, dest) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        //third
        file.mv(dest, function (err) {
            if (err) reject(err);
            resolve();
        });
    })
}

app.post('/', async(req, res) => {
    try {
        var filename = `outputs/${Date.now()}_output.json`;

        const {
            trainInput,
            trainOutput,
            testInput
        } = req.files;

        const prefix = `inputs/${req.body.caseName}`;
        await moveCsv(trainInput, `${prefix}/train_input.csv`);
        await moveCsv(trainOutput, `${prefix}/train_output.csv`);
        await moveCsv(testInput, `${prefix}/test_input.csv`);
        res.send('success');
    } catch(err) {
        res.status(500).send(err);
    }
});
```

I'm also assuming here that your `trainInput`, `trainOutput`, `testOutput` weren't all meant to be `req.files.trainInput`.

Just be careful since the synchronous nature of the `await` calls are thread blocking. If that writer function takes ages you could also looking at putting those calls onto a worker thread. Won't really matter if your requests to that server endpoint are fast and non-frequent.

Comment: Oh I took forever to answer haha I see there already is another with async/await.

Answer (score 0):

You can add **RXJS** to your project and use **Observables.forkJoin()**

Solution with Observables(**[assuming that trainInput.mv() returns Observable](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/creation/create.html)**):

```js
/* Without a selector */
var source = Rx.Observable.forkJoin(
  trainInput.mv(`inputs/${req.body.caseName}/train_input.csv`),
  trainInput.mv(`inputs/${req.body.caseName}/train_output.csv`),
  trainInput.mv(`inputs/${req.body.caseName}/test_input.csv`)
);

var subscription = source.subscribe(
  function (x) {
    // On success callback
    console.log('Success: %s', x);
  },
  function (err) {
    // Error callback
    console.log('Error');
  },
  function () {
    // Completed - runs always
    console.log('Completed');
  });

// => Success: [result_1, result_2, result_3] or Error
// => Completed
```